# Set PDF page layout to "TwoPageLeft" using JavaScript (Acrobat Pro)

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I would like to change (or add if it doesn't exist) to a PDF file with multiple pages the setting that will force the PDF to be opened in two page mode (PageLayout : TwoPageLeft for example).
I tried with that kind of JavaScript (given with Enfocus FullSwitch as example) :

```
if(($error == null) && ($doc != null))
{
try
{
    $outfile = $outfolder + '/' + $filename + ".pdf";
    $doc.layout = "TwoPageLeft";
    $doc.saveAs( {cPath : $outfile, bCopy : true});
    $outfiles.push($outfile);
}
catch(theError)
{
    $error = theError;
    $doc.closeDoc( {bNoSave : true} );
}
}
```

But it doesn't work as I would like (it will be opened with Acrobat Pro and saved as a new file without including the setting about the layout).

Does anyone can help me to correct that code to let JS open the PDF file, set the layout inside the PDF datas and save it out?

The readable information inside the PDF file should looks like this:

```
PageLayout/TwoPageLeft/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences
```

For information, I'm using FullSwitch (Enfocus) to handle files in a workflow, with Acrobat Pro, and at this time, it's only saving the file without adding the setting.

I can't find myself the answer over all the Web I searched recently, so I ask…

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I say I'm using FullSwitch from Enfocus to communicate with Acrobat Pro, would that help ? … I really try to find out my self using Google but I couldn't have an answer.

Comment: Why are you are using `$` in front of JS variables? Wehn you say "it doesn't work as I would like," what does that mean?

Comment: If you just want to change the default layout, you don't need JS. You can just use the built-in batch processing tools to change the file open options.

Comment: It is a file provided with FullSwitch (Enfocus) that I tried to edit. I didn't changed it, just tried to add the "layout" line to add the value, unsuccessfully…

Answer (score 0):

I think you copied the "this.layout = ..." line out of the Acrobat JavaScript reference documentation, correct?

When you write a JavaScript for Switch to execute (or rather for Switch to instruct Acrobat to execute for you), you should use the "$doc" variable to refer to the document Switch is processing.

So try changing the line:

```
$this.layout = "TwoColumnLeft";
```

to

```
$doc.layout = "TwoColumnLeft";
```

As you say the rest of the code works and the document is saved without errors I assume the rest of your code is correct. The change proposed here will make the adjustment in the document you're looking for.

Comment: Yes… kind of, I did write 'doc.layout' before and I changed to 'this.layout' when I found something on Google, but finally changes back. It's an error in my post. So it's still doesn't make it ! :-(

Comment: Are you sure you want to use TwoColumnLeft? Your original question talks about TwoPageLeft while your code talks about TwoColumnLeft. And have you checked the resulting document with Acrobat to see what the new setting is?

Comment: How to say… I also tried many settings like TwoPageLeft or TwoPageRight, for example. As soon as it works, I could set whatever I want. No? No matter what I set, it is always opening in default mode. Manually with Acrobat, it's working perfectly.

Comment: Can you share a result PDF file so that I can have a look what values there are in the catalog?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the PDF contains a value like "/Type/Catalog" only, in place of the "/PageLayout/TwoPageLeft/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences" I get manually with Acrobat Pro and would like to specify automatically.

Comment: I don't know what you are using to look at the PDF file structure, but have a look at pdfToolbox from callas (warning, I'm affiliated with this company) which has a PDF explore functionality. Also, there was (not sure if it still exists) a tool from Enfocus called Browser that can let you explore file contents easily as well. If I have a moment I'll try to run your script in Switch and see what happens

Comment: We're planing to give Callas pdfToolbox server a try… But we didn't have time. I think we have downloaded a demo but it was some time ago. And now I'm thinking I'm trying to do something that will only be useful if the PDF is opened with Adobe Reader, so maybe I should let it be; I didn't find a way to let Apple's Preview also open it in double page view mode… anyway… thanks.

Comment: Not a problem - and you can use the free demo version for what I suggested, not trying to sell you something here. It's not what I would typically use pdfToolbox for, but it's explore PDF functionality lets you see the internals of a PDF file and at times this can be helpful. As far as Preview is concerned, you're probably correct...